# Completeness of Linear Resolution

Tags: first-order-logic

In First order Logic linear resolution is complete. So, either linear resolution finds the empty clause or it halts.

But what assures us that linear resolution halts in a finite number of iterations if the set of clauses is satisfiable ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linear Resolution Principle - First Order Logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2652748/linear-resolution-principle-first-order-logic)

Comment: See also [Completeness of Resolution Principles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2675932/completeness-of-resolution-principles).